# L. C. Evans, weak convergence in Hilbert spaces of bounded sequences

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, weak-convergence

In last lines in the image from Lawrece. C. Evans, Partial Differentail Equations, he states that in Hilbert space every bounded sequence contains a weakly convergent subsequence.

What is wrong in my counter example ?

Let $\mathcal H$ be an infinite dimensional Hilbert space with *orthonormal* basis $\{u_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$. Take them as a sequence. Now this sequence is bounded. I don't understand what subsequence of it may converge *weakly* and to what it may converge.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sequence you gave converges weakly to $0$. Let $f$ be any bounded linear functional on $\mathcal{H}$. By the Riesz representation theorem, $f =\langle x, {-} \rangle$ for some $x \in \mathcal{H}$. Since $\{u_k\}_{k =1}^\infty$ is an orthonormal basis for $\mathcal{H}$, we have $x = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k u_k$ for some scalars $\{\alpha_k\}_{k =1}^\infty$. Now

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(u_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left\langle \sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k u_k, u_n \right\rangle = \lim_{n \to \infty} \alpha_n = 0.$$

Edit: I assumed the scalars are real here, but this argument also works over $\mathbb{C}$ (just conjugate where appropriate).

Answer (score 4):

In a Hilbert space, *any* orthonormal sequence $e_n$ converges weakly to zero. Indeed, for any vector $v$, the sequence $\langle e_n,\,v\rangle$ is $\ell^2$ (it's the coordinates of the orthogonal projection of $v$ into the closed subspaces generated by the $e_k$), so must converge to zero.

Comment: Let me see if I understand your answer correctly, any orthonormal sequence converges *weakly* to zero because $\langle u,e_k\rangle$ converges to zero as they are the coefficients of the Fourier expansion of $u$, right ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I wrote.

Comment: The statement proved in the answer is called the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.